# How can I make this code shorter? Phyphon

Tags: python

It was meant to calculate Taxes. so the x = x * 14.41 is changing by percentage.
This is the code. I would love hearing some good ideas. I thought of making it a loop or something with an list, but i dont know how exactly. i did some research. Didn't find anything.

```
    import sys
import math

x = int(input("Harry Pottah.... the boi who lived, came to die : "))
a = 100
print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVAAAAADA CAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAVRAA")
x = x / a
if x <= 100:
    x = x * 14.51
    print(x)
if x <= 150:
    x = x * 24.07
print(x)
if x <= 200:
    x = x * 26.16
print(x)
if x <= 250:
    x = x * 28.25
print(x)
if x <= 300:
    x = x * 30.34
print(x)
if x <= 350:
    x = x * 32.43
print(x)
if x <= 400:
    x = x * 34.52
print(x)
if x <= 450:
    x = x * 36.60
print(x)
if x <= 500:
    x = x * 38.69
print(x)
if x <= 550:
    x = x * 40.78
print(x)
if x <= 600:
    x = x * 42.00
print(x)

if x <= 600:
    x = x * x
print(x)

enter code here
```

Comment: You are on the right track with your loop idea!

Comment: It would be nice if we can see your attempt at it!

Comment: I tried it before continuing with the code :/ i didnt think i would get to 45 lines haha...

Comment: What would happen if x > 600? Why is *x* squared at the end? Have you considered using a lookup table?

Comment: because i would have to do it into infinity 600 isnt the maximum i have to do it into infinity so that why i lookes for a code that does that automatic

Comment: What is an lookup table?=

Comment: X is the money i type in 20000 for the amount of money i make in a year and the programm calculates the tax for it

Comment: The limit values (100, 150, 200 etc) are incrementing linearly. However, the associated values (14.51, 24.07, 26.16 etc) are not. Therefore it's impossible compare x against an infinite (?) range of values because there's no way to determine what the multiplier might be

Comment: If x = x * y
what about y ?

Comment: well... thats what i said to my teacher. unfortunatley he says that i am able to put it into 3-4 lines of code

Comment: Are you sure you want all those `if` statements and not `elif`? Now when you start with e.g. `x` as 2 before the first `if` you will multiply this number with 349.2557 (4.51 * 24.07).

Comment: Put the tax rates in a list. Convert the input (`x`) into an index in that list (ex: `index = math.ceil(max(0, x - 100) / 50)`. Return `x` times `your_list[index]`.

Comment: @user18770981 If those ranges and associated percentages are what you need to use for your homework then it's going to be impossible to do this is in 3-4 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the objective is to uplift a value by some percentage based on where that value is in some range.

The range (100, 150, 200 etc) is linear. However, the percentages are not - i.e., they cannot (apparently) be deduced based on the range limits. Thus this may be of limited assistance but shows how a lookup table might be useful.

```
lookup = [
    (100, 14.51),
    (150, 24.07),
    (200, 26.16),
    (250, 28.25),
    (300, 30.34),
    (350, 32.43),
    (400, 34.52),
    (450, 36.60),
    (500, 38.69),
    (550, 40.78),
    (600, 42.00)
    ]


def mbr(x):
    for v, p in lookup:
        if x <= v:
            return x * (1 + p / 100)
    return x

print(mbr(175))
```

**Output:**

```
220.78
```

**Note:**

This iteration over the lookup table is, arguably, inefficient although hardly significant for such a short list. If the list was much longer one could consider creating a new variable *y* being *x* rounded up to the nearest 50 then do a binary search on the lookup table based on *y*

Answer (score -1):

So, X = X * Y but it seems to no have relation between the previous and the next value of Y.
Then, i recommend you to store the value of Y in a list and then use a loop.

```py
x = input()
listY = [1.45,2.33,14.8]
for i in range(len(listY)):
  if x <= (i * 50):
    x = x * listY[i]
    print(x)
```

Comment: x=500 == IndexError

Comment: Yes my bad, try :
for i in range(len(listY))

Comment: The range of the loop must be equal to the length of your list.

Comment: It says the x isnt defined do i have to use the sys.argv?

Comment: x is just your input